# How do you attach click events to ExtJS template elements?

Tags: javascript, extjs4

How would I add a click event to each link tag in this other than by building in `onclick=....` into the XTemplate?

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<ul>',
    '<tpl for="."><li><a href="#{anchor}">{text}</a></li></tpl>',
    '</ul>'
).overwrite('someElement', [
    { text: 'Click me', anchor: '1' },
    { text: 'No, click me', anchor: '2'}
]);
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? It depends on control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is, you don't. Instead, you should use event delegation:

```
Ext.get('someElement').on('click', function(event, target) {
    console.log(target);
}, null, {delegate: 'a'});
```

This has 2 main advantages:

1. You only need to bind a single listener
2. It will work as you dynamically modify the content

Comment: I actually had to use Ext.select because I was working off of a CSS selector instead of a single node ID, but the principle worked.

Comment: How can I add event if I use tpl on panel, not dataview?

Comment: @MikeThomsen : how to do it with css selector?