# ExtJS 4.2 Custom Component fire event when click in a tpl link

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a custom component with a link into a html tpl, i need when i click in this link the component fire an event to i listen in the controller.

Code:

Ext

```
Ext.define("Ext.ux.newpanel.NewPanel", {
  extend: 'Ext.Component',
    ...
tpl: [
    '<div class="title center"><p>{title}</p></div>',
    '<div class="content center">',
    '<div class="number center"><h1>{qtd}</h1></div>',
      '<div class="ind left">',
        '{ind}',
      '</div>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="more">',
    '<a href="#" class="clickme">See all...</a>',
    '</div>'
  ],
...
```

I've tryed to create listener with delegation but i cant get the component scope into the listener.
Code:

```
..
listeners: {
    // Add the listener to the component's main el
    el: {
      delegate: '.clickme',


      click: function(ev, li) {
        // need to fire event in component here
      }
    }
  },
...
```

the event needs to be fired in the "clickme" class.

Thanks!

Comment: This has already been asked and answered in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794148/how-do-you-attach-click-events-to-extjs-template-elements

Comment: Worked for me with a little modification, i'll post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
cmp.el.on('click', function(event, target) {
 cmp.fireEvent('openRel', cmp);
}, null, {delegate: 'a'});
```

It's a little modification of this answer:
[How do you attach click events to ExtJS template elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794148/how-do-you-attach-click-events-to-extjs-template-elements)

Needs to get the DOM of the component and then delegate a click event to the  tag.